# Using the order axioms of $\mathbb{R}$ to prove the semi-definite positivity property for the absolute value?

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, absolute-value, ordered-fields

How can I use the order axioms of $\mathbb{R}$ to prove the semi-definite positivity property for the absolute value:

For all $x \in \mathbb{R}, |x|\geq0$ and $|x|=0$ if and only if $x=0$?

Comment: Hi Jake! What have you tried so far?

Comment: @user458276 I have tried proving by contradiction. So, suppose $|x|\geq0$ and $|x|=0$ and $x\neq0$. Obviously, we have a contradiction because $x$ cannot both be 0 and not 0. I just don't see the motivation behind using the order axioms of the reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 0 <= x, then -x <= 0.  Thus |x| = max(x,-x) = x >= 0.
If x <= 0, then 0 <= -x.  Thus |x| = max(x,-x) = -x >= 0.

If |x| = 0, then x = 0 or -x = 0.  Thus x = 0.
If x = 0, then |x| = 0.